# Rarefaction Shock Wave Interaction

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-pde

I am interested in explicit solutions in 1D for the interaction of a rarefaction wave with a shock wave of arbitrary strength. The book **Supersonic Flow and Shock Waves** by Courant and Friedricks states:

"When the interaction of rarefaction waves with contact interfaces or shocks is considered, then the method of finite difference is apparently more tractable than any explicit representation of the solution"

For a weak shock wave, the book presents a solution based on the simple wave assumption. When one considers shocks of arbitrary shock strength, the entropy is no longer neglected and the mathematical treatment is more complex. It has been a while since the book is published. I was wondering if there have been any analytical solutions to this problem? Reference to papers or general comments will be appreciated -abiyo